# Writing xml and reading it back c#

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

ok, I am now using the document method for writing my XML instead of the XmlWriter.
I have written my XML file with.

```
userNode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("user");
attribute = xmlDoc.CreateAttribute("age");
attribute.Value = "39";
userNode.Attributes.Append(attribute);
userNode.InnerText = "Jane Doe";
rootNode.AppendChild(userNode);
```

But the question is again how to read these settings back.

```
<users>
  <user name="John Doe" age="42" />
  <user name="Jane Doe" age="39" />
</users>
```

The format of the file I can figure out how to read the **age** variable but can't get my hands on the name property. my XML file is slightly different to above but not by much

Comment: Your file should look very different, because `"Jane Doe"` is not an attribute in the code that writes it.

Comment: It does but the question is still valid, the name part I cant get my hands on it.

Comment: <Property Name="some text">4.5</Property> its the name I cant read back

Comment: Please show the C# code you used to attempt to get the name. And show the actual XML. Showing us different XML is ridiculous; is the name in an attribute or InnerText? If you yourself don't know what your XML is or what you want from it, no wonder you can't get anything to work.

Comment: currently iam using node to read and write but iam missing a closing property tag, I have tried to alter the ending but to no avail, its still readable and writable where to go from here I guess I need to close the property tag, heras my write code.

Comment: XmlNode userNode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Property");
            XmlAttribute attribute = xmlDoc.CreateAttribute("default");
            attribute.Value = "4.5";
            userNode.Attributes.Append(attribute);
            attribute = xmlDoc.CreateAttribute("amount");
            attribute.Value = "4.5";
            userNode.Attributes.Append(attribute);
            attribute = xmlDoc.CreateAttribute("name");
            attribute.Value = "Some ssetting";
            userNode.Attributes.Append(attribute);
            rootNode.AppendChild(userNode);   Ňuf,  Alan wolman

Answer (score 5):

Writing XML files element by element can be quite time consuming - and susceptible to errors.

I would suggest using an XML Serializer for this type of job.

If you are not concerned with the format - and the requirement is just to be able to serialize to XML and deserialize at a later time the code can be as simple as follows:

```
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

string filepath = @"c:\temp\users.xml";

var usersToStore = new List<User>
{
     new User { Name = "John Doe", Age = 42 },
     new User { Name = "Jane Doe", Age = 29 }
};

using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(usersToStore.GetType());
    serializer.Serialize(fs, usersToStore);
}

 var retrievedUsers = new List<User>();
 using (FileStream fs2 = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open))
 {
     XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(usersToStore.GetType());
     retrievedUsers = serializer.Deserialize(fs2) as List<User>;
 }
```

Microsoft provides some good examples in the [.Net documentation - Introducing XML Serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/serialization/introducing-xml-serialization)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `System.Xml` (it's more clear to use):

For Saving:

```
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
...
xdoc.Save("test.xml");
```

For Reading:

```
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
...
xdoc.Load("test.xml");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [XDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)  class instead of XmlDocument, if you can. It is much easier to work with. To write and then read your XML, you can do this:

```
var fileName = @"foo.xml";

// Write XML
var xdoc = new XDocument(
    new XElement("users",
        new XElement("user",
            new XAttribute("name", "John Doe"),
            new XAttribute("age", "42")),
        new XElement("user",
            new XAttribute("name", "Jane Doe"),
            new XAttribute("age", "39"))));

xdoc.Save(fileName);

// Read XML
var xdoc2 = XDocument.Load(fileName);
foreach (var userxml in xdoc2.Root.Elements("user"))
{
    var name = userxml.Attribute("name");
    var age = userxml.Attribute("age");
    // use values as needed ...
}
```