# Writing xml and reading it back c# with xample xml output

Tags: c#, xml

Ok I am using again xmldocument to write an xml file then read it back in simple right but how to get the age this time in this example? I was asked to produce the whole problem before so here it is.

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlNode rootNode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("users");
        xmlDoc.AppendChild(rootNode);

        XmlNode userNode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("user");
        XmlAttribute attribute = xmlDoc.CreateAttribute("age");
        attribute.Value = "42";
        userNode.Attributes.Append(attribute);
        userNode.InnerText = "John Doe";
        rootNode.AppendChild(userNode);

        userNode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("user");
        attribute = xmlDoc.CreateAttribute("age");
        attribute.Value = "39";
        userNode.Attributes.Append(attribute);
        userNode.InnerText = "Jane Doe";
        rootNode.AppendChild(userNode);
        xmlDoc.Save("c:\\temp\\testdoc.xml");
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string files = "c:\\temp\\testdoc.xml";

        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.Load(files);
        foreach (XmlNode node  in xmlDoc)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(node.SelectSingleNode("user").InnerText);
            MessageBox.Show(node.SelectSingleNode("age").InnerText);

        }

    }
I can read the users name correctly but not the age I get an error.


<users>
 <user age="42">John Doe</user>
 <user age="39">Jane Doe</user>
</users>
```

Comment: System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

System.Xml.XmlNode.SelectSingleNode(...) returned null

Comment: You have this question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44477727/writing-xml-and-reading-it-back-c-sharp.  This answer to the present question is here: 
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/44478352/4065876.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the attributes array directly on the node with

```
MessageBox.Show(node.SelectSingleNode("user").Attributes["age"].InnerText);
```

Comment: Thank you. In my example I use a single node and get a single reply how to do it with multiple nodes though? the above gets me one node when two infact exist.